# Are there any means to allow for more complex type inference in C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference

Suppose I have a template function:

```
template<class T>
void whenMatchesType(std::function<void(T*)> action) { ... }
```

I might invoke this like so:

```
anObject.whenMatchesType<SomeType>([=](SomeType *value) {
    // ...
});
```

Although C++ is capable of inferring template parameters from arguments of simple, non-template types, I don't seem to be able to omit explicitly specifying the type (as `<SomeType>`) in this case - even though it is provided as a type parameter to the first argument.

Is there some change to my code - or to my compilation - through which I might avoid this redundancy?

Comment: No, the compiler won't say "Hey, if I instantiate a `std::function` with the type of that argument and convert the argument to that `std::function` type, I can instantiate `whenTypeMatches` with that new type and pass the argument that I created instead of the one that the function was called with, and everything will work (I think?)". That way lies madness. <g>

Comment: The solution in this particular example is to get rid of that `std::function`. `template <class Fn> void whenMatchesType(const Fn& action)`. Why does the code require `std::function`?

Comment: `anObject.whenMatchesType(std::function(lambda))`. Not as nice, but at least you don't repeat the template.

Comment: I second Pete. The answer to this question depends on why you are using `std::function` in your signature to begin with. If you can tell us why you think you need it, we can probably tell you a better way to achieve the same result without having to use `std::function`s.

Comment: @super In this case, it's because I need access to the type `T` from within the function. the function in question is essentially a shorthand to check that the object is of a certain type, and if so, work with it as that type.

Comment: @EthanMcTague Are you using c++17?

Comment: @super I'm using C++20 actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need acces to the parameter type you can still take in the callable as it's own template parameter, then use type traits to extract the information.

Here is a simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct parameter_type;

template <typename ReturnType, typename ParameterType>
struct parameter_type<std::function<ReturnType(ParameterType)>> {
    using ParameterT = ParameterType;
};

template <typename T>
using param_t = typename parameter_type<decltype(std::function{std::declval<T>()})>::ParameterT;

template<class T>
void whenMatchesType(T) {
    using Parameter = param_t<T>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Parameter, int>, "Only callables that take int as parameter is allowed");
}

int main() {
    whenMatchesType([](int){});
    //whenMatchesType([](double){});
}
```